# Python-flask "got an unexpected keyword argument"

Tags: python, flask

Tengo dos operaciones **complejas con distintas variables para cada una (para simplificarlo digamos que es una suma y una resta)**. Cada una se hace en distintas html: suma.html - resta.html. Comparto código index.py completo. En suma.html y resta.html simplemente tengo 3 campos input y el boton calcular:

> N1 - N2 - PASSWD_STATUS

> Calcular

Hay que estar logueado previamente para poder hacerlas (eso lo tengo solucionado) y además **colocar un 1** en el input PASSWD_STATUS. Al intentar darle al botón de cálculo me aparece:

> line 31, in checkinPass
> payload['resta']= resta(**payload)#TypeError: resta() got an unexpected keyword argument 'passwd_status'

Agradezco una ayuda ya que probé muchas variantes y no pude solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "abc"  

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])

def checkinPass():
    n1 = request.form.get('n1')
    n2 = request.form.get('n2')
    # Flag para guardar el estado del login
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        # Dict donde vamos a guardar la info
        payload = {'passwd_status': False,'n1': 0,'n2': 0,'suma': 0,'resta': 0}
        data = request.form.get('password') # Recogemos el valor que nos manda el usuario
        try:
            # Recogemos los parámetros que envia el usuario
            n1 = float(request.form.get('n1', 0))
            n2 = float(request.form.get('n2', 0))    
        except ValueError as e:
            return {}, 400
        # a este IF se entra con el password correcto = 1
        if data == '1':
            payload['passwd_status'] = True
            payload['n1']= n1
            payload['n2']= n2
            # Añadimos el resultado del cálculo a nuestro payload
            payload['suma'] = suma(**payload)
            payload['resta']= resta(**payload) #TypeError: resta() got an unexpected keyword argument 'passwd_status'
        return payload

def suma(**payload):
    n1 = payload['n1']
    n2 = payload['n2']
    suma = n1 + n2
    return suma

def resta(**payload):
    n1 = payload['n1']
    n2 = payload['n2']
    suma = n1 - n2
    return resta

# Session para login
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form['email']
        session["user"]= user #crea la sesion
        return redirect(url_for('user'))
    else:
        if "user" in session:
            return redirect(url_for('user')) #si ya está logueado y quiere ir a login lo redirige a /user
        return render_template('login.html')

# Ruta para SUMA
@app.route('/user')
def user():  
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        return render_template("suma.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))

# Ruta para RESTA
@app.route('/resta')
def resta(): #TypeError: resta() got an unexpected keyword argument 'passwd_status'
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        return render_template("resta.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: A cual de las dos funciones llamadas resta deseas llamar? A la primera o a la segunda? Lo pregunto por que la segunda función llamada resta reemplaza a la primera.

Comment: Hola Dante! ahi modifiqué un comentario para que se entienda. El llamado depende de en qué página esté, si estoy en "suma.html" y le doy al botón calcular, que sume. Y si estoy en "resta.html" que me brinde la resta (reitero que en realidad son dos operaciones distintas con distintas variables, lo ejemplifiqué con una suma y una resta)

Comment: A lo que me refería, es que tienes dos funciones resta: `def resta(**payload):` y `@app.route('/resta') def resta():`. Cuando la llamas, llamas a la segunda (que reemplazó la primera). Y la segunda función resta NO acepta argumentos. Revisaste que ambas funciones se llamen diferente en tu código original?

Comment: sii, es cierto lo que decis. No veo como poder solucionarlo, estoy atorado. Si por ejemplo edito el segundo def `@app.route('/resta') def resta2():` obviamente no se va a arreglar

Comment: Y si editas solo el primer def y el segundo lo dejas como está?

Comment: sii, muchas gracias Dante

pd: no hay que programar de madrugada porque pasan estas cosas

Comment: De nada compañero xD